# Adding upload code to google form

Tags: html, forms, upload

I'm trying to add a script to my google form that will allow those who fill it out to upload a file.  I've found a script that will allow entrants to upload their file to my google drive, but I can't figure out how to write this script into my form.  Is this possible, or do I have to copy and paste the form code into my existing "upload" code?  I'm not a professional coder and only have basic knowledge of how to do this.

Comment: It's possible to do file uploads, but you'll need to be more specific before we can help you - e.g. Adding your code that you have written so far.